# CSS to popup window from IFrame

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have a page which has an iframe.

The iframe has a button which opens a new popup window.

I want a CSS to be applied to the popup window.

The page for the popup window is a third party application.
So I cannot add CSS for that.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply css directly. But with js you can add style tag to iframe content - and put rule there ( or link to css file )